# What happens if a deva comes to remember all his past lives?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm playing a deva and I wanted to know what happens if my character manages to remember all his past lives? Does he gain all the experience he accumulated during all those lives or does nothing happen and he just remembers some old memory?

It's said in #374 Dragon Magazine that some devas can remember their past lives: it's rare but possible. So if we exclude the benefit from Memory of a Thousand Lives, would the fact a deva has remembered all his past lives change the dynamic of the game?

Comment: Haven't played 4e, but considering what you're mentioning is pretty much racial flavor text I'm pretty sure they'd just be mundane memories- even if your mind can remember that you used to be able to do something in particular, your reincarnated body wouldn't necessarily have the muscle memory to actually pull it off.

Comment: Doesn't the Memory of a Thousand Lifetimes encounter power assume this sort of thing is going on all the time, but it is fleeting? You remember something when you need it, but it's not a permanent thing?

Comment: @arnaktotal Can you add some more detail to your question to improve it? What do you already know about devas, from what sourcebooks (phb2, right?). Why did this question arise in your game, and why don't the rules you know answer it? I'm happy to edit your grammar again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Summary

Devas are described in the *Player's Handbook 2* (PH2), with supplemental information in an article entitled *Ecology of the Deva*, which can be found in Dragon Magazine #374 (DM374).

There's no direct mechanical benefit from remembering all of your past lives. However, DM374 describes a "transcendent deva" and says that

> Commonly for a transcendent deva, all the details of all the deva’s past lives can be recalled at will.

You can certainly roleplay your deva as approaching transcendence, and can choose to take mechanical bonuses that revolve around this theme as you level.

---

### Deva Flavor

The description of devas in the PH2 class section makes it clear that all devas have some memories of past lives, but that those memories vary in their quality from deva to deva. The flavor text for the *Memory of a Thousand Lifetimes* racial power says:

> The dreamlike memories of your previous lives lend insight to aid you.

DM374 makes it sound like these memories are less clear and accessible, saying that

> The deva’s new physical body-mind, more limited than a spiritual form, cannot contain the
>   weighty memories of myriad lifetimes. These slip away so the deva can experience life anew, unpolluted by notions formed in another time and place. However, such memories remain ingrained just out of conscious reach, accessible in meaningful visions, insights, and dreams. The deva’s new body and mind are wholly different, perhaps even down to
>   the sex.

However, there are a few passages that imply that a deva can gain greater access to their memories over time, including the quote in this answer's summary. There also exist mechanical options to represent this.

The *Soul Recognition* section of DM374 says that

> Clear memory fails devas when they reincarnate, at least until one approaches or achieves
>   transcendence.

'Transcendence' is described as "a deva rising above the normal state of being" and "reaching an ultimate level of spiritual perfection". Devas who transcend may become demigods or exarchs, stay in the world as a transcendent deva, or something else.

### Mechanical Options

Mechanically, you can represent your Deva's improving memory by taking feats that improve your racial power, and with a paragon path.

There are multiple racial feats that improve the *Memory of a Thousand Lifetimes* racial ability in PH2, including:

- Auspicious Lineage: add a d8 instead of a d6
- Ascendant Lineage: power is not expended if the roll still fails
- Transcendent Lineage: may reroll the die and use either result

as well as some in DM374:

- Immortal Skill: treat below average skill or ability check modifying rolls as average
- Scourge of the Fallen: enhances the power when used to attack evil immortal creatures
- Immortal Resilience: treat below average saving throw modifying rolls as average
- Immortal Prowess: treat below average attack roll modifying rolls as average

There is also a racial paragon path in PH2 that you could use to represent attaining this complete memory: *Ancestral Ascendant*. In the description it says:

> All devas have at least a tenuous connection to their past lives ... for you the connection to your past lives is more tangible.

and that

> Those who have the temerity to face you in battle learn that they aren't fighting just the present-day incarnation of you, but also every incarnation of you that has ever been.